# How to detect calling class in objective c static method

Tags: objective-c, class, inheritance, factory-method

How does one detect the calling class from within a static method such that if the class is subclassed the subclass is detected? (See comment inside MakeInstance)

```
@interface Widget : NSObject
+ (id) MakeInstance;
@end

@implementation Widget
+ (id) MakeInstance{
    Class klass = //How do I get this?
    id instance = [[klass alloc] init];
    return instance;
}
@end

@interface UberWidget : Widget
//stuff
@end

@implementation UberWidget
//Stuff that does not involve re-defining MakeInstance
@end

//Somewhere in the program
UberWidget* my_widget = [UberWidget MakeInstance];
```

Comment: There are no static methods in Objective-C. Instead, there are class methods such as the one you've shown in your example. Note that method names should begin with a lowercase letter, e.g., `makeInstance` rather than `MakeInstance`.

Comment: note that this is one of the important distinctions between Objective-C and Java and C++ -- in Java and C++ it would be impossible to do this

Comment: @jlehr Thanks for the extra info. **Where I work, the upper case method name is the style convention for factory methods. I'll convey your concern to them ;)

Comment: If you're targeting Apple's platforms you'd be better off following their guidelines. Project teams that don't follow prevailing conventions aren't establishing new ones -- they're just undermining those that already exist. Nothing is accomplished by doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the appropriate solution for what you are trying to accomplish is this:

```
+ (id) MakeInstance{
    id instance = [[self alloc] init];
    return instance;
}
```

And as Cyrille points out, it should probably return `[instance autorelease]` if you want to follow convention (and aren't using ARC).

Comment: That should do it, assuming you add an `autorelease` to your initializer.

Answer (score 2):

UIAdam's solution is perfectly fine for your case. Although if you want to detect, more specifically, from which class is you method called, use `[self class]` on objects, or simply `self` for classes.